Help Needed for Solar Battery Charger Design Using CN3795
I have created a solar battery charger using the CN3795 IC. The goal is for the panel to output 2A at 5V. The panel characteristics are as follows: 50W, Vmp of 17.22V, and Imp of 2.91A.
For the creation of the charger, I based my design on two documents:
The datasheet of the CN3795 (attached as Document 1), which provides formulas for calculating the values of resistors connected to the FB pin and the resistors connected to the MPPT pin, as well as the value of Rcs that determines my output current, which in this case is 2A.
A project by another person that includes additional protection enhancements (attached as Document 2).
I used these references to create my circuit in EasyEDA. As a novice in circuit design, I have two main questions:
What alternative component can I use instead of the DMP6023LE-13?
If anyone who has designed a circuit with the CN3795 can spot any errors or potential improvements in my design, I would be very grateful.
Attachments:

CN3795 Datasheet
Reference Project with Protection Enhancements
My Solar Battery Charge desing

Circuit Images.
**- CN3795 Datasheet circuit **

**- Reference Project with Protection Enhancements circuit **

**- My Solar Battery Charge desing **

Thank you in advance for your assistance!
